# uiwebview zoom programmatically

Tags: uiwebview, uiscrollview, zooming

I want to change the UIWebView zoom level programmatically.

I have tried these but they are not worked for me ;

```
    UIScrollView *sv = [theWebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
 [sv setZoomScale:50 animated:YES];
```

also,

```
  [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 5.0;"];
```

Any idea?

Comment: First of all, if you read Apple doc carefully then the default maximum value for zooming is 1.0f. Here it is, `@property(nonatomic) CGFloat zoomScale NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);            // default is 1.0`. You are inserting 50 as parameter?

Answer (score 8):

This is the only way I could find to accomplish it:
(specify your own sizes if you wish, i was attempting to zoom out after typing into a form field)

```
UIScrollView *sv = [[webViewView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[sv zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sv.contentSize.width, sv.contentSize.height) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Nice! Been looking for this all over SO. Thank you!

Comment: As well with IOS5 you can now call webview.scrollview

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
UIScrollView * sv = self.theWebview.scrollView;

[sv setZoomScale:50];
```

where `self` is the `viewController` containing the `webView`.

Your problem could be the size of your `zoomScale` exceeds the size of `sv.maximumZoomScale`.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIScrollView * sv = yourwebview_outlet.scrollView;
[sv setZoomScale:50];
```